# Mapping XML to models when list node name and item node name are the same

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am writing a client for a API and I am trying to map the top response here to my models:
https://github.com/harvesthq/api/blob/master/Sections/Invoice%20Messages.md

This is my InvoiceMessageCollection

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "invoice-message")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class InvoiceMessageCollection
        implements Iterable<InvoiceMessage>
{
    @XmlElement(name = "invoice-message")
    private List<InvoiceMessage> list = new ArrayList<InvoiceMessage>();

    public List<InvoiceMessage> getList()
    {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<InvoiceMessage> list)
    {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public static InvoiceMessageCollection fromInputStream(final InputStream xml)
            throws HarvestClientException
    {
        try
        {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(InvoiceMessageCollection.class);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
            return (InvoiceMessageCollection) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new HarvestClientException("Unable to parse XML into InvoiceItemCategory.", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<InvoiceMessage> iterator()
    {
        return this.list.iterator();
    }
}
```

The problem is that both the list and the item has the same node name. This is clearly a bug in their API since this is the only call where these have the same name, but still - is there a way I can fix this and still use JAXB?

The actual exception is thrown on `return (InvoiceMessageCollection) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);` since InvoiceMessage can't be cast to InvoiceMessageCollection.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.enonic.harvestclient.exceptions.HarvestClientException: Unable to parse XML into InvoiceItemCategory.
        at com.enonic.harvestclient.models.InvoiceMessageCollection.fromInputStream(InvoiceMessageCollection.java:45)
        at com.enonic.harvestclient.DefaultHarvestClient.getInvoiceMessages(DefaultHarvestClient.java:315)
        at com.enonic.harvestclient.Testing.main(Testing.java:22)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.enonic.harvestclient.models.InvoiceMessage cannot be cast to com.enonic.harvestclient.models.InvoiceMessageCollection
        at com.enonic.harvestclient.models.InvoiceMessageCollection.fromInputStream(InvoiceMessageCollection.java:41)
        ... 7 more
```

Comment: can you post that exception stack trace

Comment: @bhutto edited with stacktrace now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the same element name `invoice-message` for both `@XmlRootElement` and `@XmlElement` won't cause any problems for JAXB.  The exception appears to be in your own code.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.enonic.harvestclient.models.InvoiceMessage cannot be cast to com.enonic.harvestclient.models.InvoiceMessageCollection
        at com.enonic.harvestclient.models.InvoiceMessageCollection.fromInputStream(InvoiceMessageCollection.java:41)
        ... 7 more
```

---

### UPDATE

> My InvoiceMessage model also has @XmlRootElement(name =
>   "invoice-message") since there are calls for single invoice messages.
>   This makes JAXB think that returned list is actually a message.

You can't have that.  Instead of annotating `InvoiceMessageCollection` with `@XmlRootElement` you should use one of the unmarshal methods that take a `Class` parameter.

```
 InvoiceMessageCollection imc = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml, InvoiceMessageCollection.class).getValue();
```

Comment: My InvoiceMessage model also has @XmlRootElement(name = "invoice-message") since there are calls for single invoice messages. This makes JAXB think that returned list is actually a message.